# jQuery replace a word in content with word in a URL string

Tags: jquery, replace

I'm trying to change a word in the entire page (multiple occurrences) with a word passed in the URL string. I'm using it with WordPress. Also since it's WP, I'd like to know if it's better to do this with jQuery or if I should try to get it working server-side instead?

This is the code I have so far but it's not doing it for some reason. I'm not sure if I need ajaxStop, I just added it in due to an answer I found in SO.

```
function replaceText() {
    var city = document.URL.split('?')[1];
    var replaced = jQuery("body").html().replace(new RegExp("/Houston/g", city));
    jQuery("body").html(replaced);
}
jQuery(document).ready(replaceText);
jQuery("html").ajaxStop(replaceText);
```

Comment: You should ideally do this server side. Doing it on the client side can potentially break all event bindings.

Comment: @techfoobar Gotcha.  Yea I'll close this question then and do it server side.  I kinda had a hunch that would be a better solution anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
function replaceText() {
    var city = document.URL.split('?')[1];
    var replaced = jQuery("body").html().replace(/Houston/g, city));
    jQuery("body").html(replaced);
}
jQuery(document).ready(replaceText).on('ajaxStop',replaceText);
```